How to create a video encoding ladder for any aspect ratio?
For a given video uploaded by a user, I need to create three versions of it to cover standard definition (SD), high definition (HD), full high definition (FHD), and ultra high definition (UHD e.g. 4K).  "resolution/encoding ladders" for standard aspect ratios like 16:9 and 4:3.
For 4:3 we might have:
640 x 480
960 x 720
1440 x 1080
2880 x 2160

For 16:9 we might have:
854 x 480
1280 x 720
1920 x 1080
3840 x 2160

If a user uploads a file in either of those aspect ratios, we can create the four different versions because the resolution standards are known.
However if a user uploads a video with an unforseen aspect ratio, say 23:19, then how would you go about formatting that video into SD, HD, FHD, and UHD versions?
If a 23:19 video is indeed uploaded then I am not looking to resize it to fit a different 'standard' aspect ratio. It must remain the same aspect ratio, but have four quality versions. The problem is what height and width sizes to create for non-standard resolutions?
I have already come accross many aspect ratios like 16:10, 21:9, 1.85:1, 2.39:1. How could I take care of making quality variations of those?
I am using Node.js and FFMpeg for video processing.
